# Cmd window hangs and JOption show Msg doesn't display

Tags: java, stringbuilder, break, freeze, joptionpane

I am trying to ask the user for a full name input, which I'll extract the first character from the first name, and the second name. I will also ask the user for their street address, which I'll be extracting the housing unit number from the address.

The plan is for user to input something like: John Smith. Address: 1234 Main St.
And after processing, the output would be JS1234.

I compile and execute properly through the first two dialog 
boxes, but the command window will hang, and not produce the final
showMessageDialog box with the intended output. I have to Ctrl + C 
to break the execution. I think I need to 
involve StringBuilder somehow but not sure how to with JOption.

Thanks,

Jeremy

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class ConstructID
    {
            public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            String name;
            String aInitial = "";
            String bInitial = "";
            String sAdd;
            String unit = "";
            int i;
            int j;

            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                           "Please enter your full name. ");
            sAdd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                           "Please enter your street address. ");

            i = 0;
            while(i < name.length())
            {
                if(name.charAt(i) == ' ')
                { 
                    aInitial = name.substring(0, i);
                    bInitial = name.substring(i + 1, name.length());
                    i = name.length();
                    ++i;
                }
            }
            j = 0;
            while(j < sAdd.length())
            {
                if(sAdd.charAt(j) == ' ')
                {
                    unit = sAdd.substring(0, j);
                    j = sAdd.length();
                    ++j;
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your unique ID is " + 
                        aInitial + bInitial + unit);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loops are causing infinite loop when first character is not space. You never increment the loop counters unless you get a space character so it will hang on any no space character.

Also for this kind of parsing you could use String.split() or use regexp.

Comment: I'm not even sure what String.split() or regexp are yet...To eliminate the issue with the infinite loop based on the ' ' I had in the charAt(), I separated the name String into two: firstName and secondName.  This way I wouldn't have to worry about extracting to characters from one input.  However, even with the deletion of the space character, I'm still left with a hanging terminal.